# Put Button in the Right Center of layer?

Tags: android, android-layout

i want the bottom button (button1) in the right center of relative layout 
the layout exists under fragment

i used this attribute

android:layout_gravity="right|center_horizontal"

but no reaction  as photo

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRlA8.jpg

can u help me ?

the XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >



 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/topLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="36dp"

        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:ellipsize="start"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="@string/search"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColorHint="#c7c7c7"
        android:width="250dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="38dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="#359c5e"
        android:onClick="geoLocate"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:text="@string/go"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</LinearLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/belowlayout"
    android:layout_below="@id/topLayout" />


<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/belowlayout"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<Button
  android:id="@+id/button1"
  android:layout_width="100dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
   android:layout_gravity="right|center_horizontal"
  android:background="@drawable/botton_corner"
  android:text="Next"
  android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i make relative layout under fragment and want to put button in the right in the center of this layer,
the issue when make the gravity attribute no action happen 

the padding of botton from bottom is large from the top in the layer

Comment: the photo is 
http://imgur.com/38hX8mV

Comment: @AymanEmad: Please see my edited answer - it should do what you want..

Comment: i make your changes no action , can u write the full code ?

Comment: i want as photo 
http://imgur.com/38hX8mV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of your `RelativeLayout` **belowlayout** try below

```
   <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/belowlayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="#359c5e"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Next"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: no mr Hariharan , i want this button under fragment at right in the center of relative layout

Comment: the bottom layout ( relative layout ) contain button , i want this button  in the right at center of layout and the top padding and bottom is equal

Comment: worked well , thanks sir , can i be communicated with u sir ?

Answer (score 0):

This could be what want. The button is in the "right layout", centered to its left side.

EDIT: if you want the button to be centered in the second half of the layout, use this:

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

If you want it to be alignt to right side, use this:

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Button"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you have to use the properties of relative layout like
<Button
 android:align_parentright="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way. Hope this works for you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColorHint="#c7c7c7"
            android:width="250dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="38dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="#359c5e"
            android:onClick="geoLocate"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:text="@string/go"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/botton_corner"
        android:text="Next"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/playButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/play_button"
                android:visibility="visible" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```